# Gitlab - "letsencrypt['enable'] = true" produce error in reconfigure

Tags: gitlab

I installed Gitlab 12.7.6 on CentOS7
I follow the instruction [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/ssl.html) for configure the SSL
it said to

> letsencrypt['enable'] = true                      # GitLab 10.5 and 10.6 require this option

When I changed it to 'true' and run 'gitlab-ctl reconfigure'  I get the error:

> > There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:
>
> letsencrypt_certificate[gitlab.mydomain]
>   (letsencrypt::http_authorization line 5) had an error: RuntimeError:
>   acme_certificate[staging]
>   (/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/letsencrypt/resources/certificate.rb
>   line 25) had an error: RuntimeError: ruby_block[create certificate for
>   gitlab.mydomain]
>   (/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/acme/resources/certificate.rb
>   line 108) had an error: RuntimeError: [gitlab.mydomain] Validation
>   failed, unable to request certificate
>
> Running handlers complete Chef Client failed. 18 resources updated in
>   01 minutes 08 seconds

When it set as 'false' I get no error.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get SSL support with letsencrypt your machine should have a Fully Qualified Domain Name. From the error it looks like your machine is called `gitlab.mydomain`, so either you are running it in LAN only, in which case you should disable letsencrypt, or you have not set correctly its domain name in gitlab configuration.

Comment: which configuration file contain the domain setting?